# Sphinx - MySQL query between/larger than

Tags: mysql, sphinx, between

I have Sphinx running to index my MySQL query's.

When I do the following SQL query I get a perfect result:

```
SELECT * FROM huisjesIndex WHERE MATCH('@formatted "^20120901$"') ORDER BY huis_contract DESC, global_points DESC LIMIT 200,20;
```

But I would like to replace `MATCH('@formatted "^20120901$"')` with a larger/smaller than query. In SQL I would do the following: formatted `BETWEEN 20120901 AND 20120931`. Unfortunately this draws an error on Sphinx.

Can anyone give me the syntax of the SQL query to do a query on a range? I need this to get results for the entire 201209 month.

**EDIT**

I was able to answer my own question.

When using MATCH() the value described has to be a field (because you are string searching).

When you do a compare like 'int >= 0' then the int must be an attribute.

Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: According to documentation http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/1.10/sphinxql-select.html, `BETWEEN` is supported. Can you show us the query that is failing? What error message do you get?